# Exchange 2010 High Avaibility Solution planning architecture

Tags: exchange-2010, high-availability, network-design

I'm planning to deploy Exchange 2010 in organization. This organization consists of 2 sites.

The plan for 1st location (holding most of the employees) is:
- 2 x Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - Forefront TMG Servers working in NLB
- 1 x Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with CAS ROLE (and EDGE?) behind TMG
- 1 x Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with MAILBOX AND HUB in DAG

The plan for 2nd location is (holding just couple of employees, eventually some external hosting):
- 1 router (if necessary TMG server if not just simple hw box)
- 1 x Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with CAS ROLE (and EDGE?) behind TMG
- 1 x Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with MAILBOX AND HUB in DAG.

Those 2 locations will be connected thru IPSEC permanently.

1. Considering that I will have TMG servers do i need to put EDGE servers outside? or I can keep them with CAS role.
2. Will DAG work thru IPSEC tunnel efficiently ?
3. Is this even good plan ? What would be the best plan considering we have 3-4 locations people need perm access thru IPSEC tunnel to access mail and we need HA solution. We're putting mail servers in 2 locations since we want to be sure one or the other works and accept emails, serves them in case of power failure or network failure in one of the locations.

Comment: @MadBoy - Is your Active Directory configured with multiple sites, or just one?

Comment: All our locations are connected thru IPSEC now and have access to AD. Plan is to make it better so most likely there will also be local AD server too.

Comment: But do you have multiple sites configured in Active Directory Sites and Services? Depending if you have only one site or multiple sites depends on the way to implement HA.

Comment: Only one, default site. But depending on need we can implement more if necessary.

Comment: @MadBoy, How'd you manage to deploy the TMG 2010 as failover / HA cluster ? I'm interested in knowing that actually ?

Comment: We're still doing it - took a while to prepare stuff (but it's gonna be done in less then a month). What information do you need?